# How to create VHS video tape distortion effects with FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I've been attempting to create video that looks like it's been distorted by a VHS video tape player. A specific example of the effect I'm after is the tape distortion effects [seen near the end of this video](https://youtu.be/4JDnemMYYSQ), but general tape distortion is the main thing.

I cannot work out a way to do that with just FFmpeg (and potentially frei0r filters) though. Is there a way to do that, or am I stuck? I'm just looking for video distortion, as I can do audio distortion just fine with my current tools.

Things I have attempted so far:

- Strange combinations of blend modes in Kdenlive.
- The chromashift filter in FFmpeg.
- Converting the video to uncompressed YUV, messing with the file using Audacity, and then converting back to MP4 (this produced interesting results but not ones I was looking for).
- Separating the video into its component channels, messing with levels and position, and then recomposing it.

Comment: "I cannot work out a way to do that" – please show what you've already tried and where you think this should be improved.

Answer (score 2):

The most prominent effect I see is an embossing effect.

That can be carried out using ffmpeg's convolution filter as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf convolution="-2 -1 0 -1 1 1 0 1 2:-2 -1 0 -1 1 1 0 1 2:-2 -1 0 -1 1 1 0 1 2:-2 -1 0 -1 1 1 0 1 2" -c:a copy out
```

I've taken the coefficients straight from the docs at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#convolution

Answer (score -3):

You might be looking for the
[frei0r plugin](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#frei0r-1) of FFmpeg.

An example for adding the frei0r parameter is `-vf frei0r=pixeliz0r?...`.

If you wish to examine the various effects in action, demonstrations
can be found in the blog article
[Experiments with FFmpeg Filters and Frei0r Plugin Effects](https://yalantis.com/blog/experiments-with-ffmpeg-filters-and-frei0r-plugin-effects/).

Comment: -1. The OP says `I cannot work out a way to do that with just FFmpeg (and potentially frei0r filters) though. Is there a way to do that, or am I stuck?` Then your answer points to the *already known tool*, gives a *generic* example and a link. What? Even if any solution to the *specific* problem is in the linked article, the answer is link-only at best.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: "I cannot work out a way to do" is not very informative, so I wish this answer to start a dialog about what is he doing that is different from the documentation or from the article, although the information in both links should be enough. I can't write here a blog with *everything".

Comment: Answers are not meant for starting dialogues. If the question is not sufficiently clear, it should be improved first.

Comment: OK, I can see your point. If the OP states this generic answer is what they want then I will revoke my downvote. If the question is improved and it demands a specific answer, and your answer is edited to address this, then I will revoke my downvote (and possibly vote up, this scenario would be the best). Please leave me a comment when these conditions apply so I can fulfill my promise.